# jQuery form plugin, submit in the wordpress way

Tags: jquery, uploads, ajax, forms

Trying to use jQuery [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) in wordpress site to upload files.

HTML markup:

```
<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="file" value="" name="file_upload"  class="file_upload"/> <br></br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn_submit" name="btn_submit" />


</form>
```

and the JS snippet :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

The form processes its element values in `process.php` which is a non-template file. As a result Wordpress codex functions are not available in that page . So what I need to do is to use the jQuery form plugin's ajax submission in the wordpressian  way.

How to implement that ?

---

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the WordPress functions in your process.php file then there is a way for you.

simply put these two lines of code at the top of your process.php file

```
$blogheader = explode("wp-content",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
include $blogheader[0]."wp-blog-header.php";
```

Now you can use the WordPress functions in your file and do what you want.
Will that work for you?

Comment: I also need to add these lines `include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';` to get other functions such as `wp_handle_upload()`  to work. And this not the recommended  wordpressian way However, I think.